# Change table column name parquet format Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, parquet

I have table with columns a,b,c.
The data store on hdfs as parquet, is it possible to change specific column name even if the parquet already writted with the schema of a,b,c?

Answer (score 1):

read file in a loop
create a new df with changed column name 
write new df in append mode in another dir
move this new dir to read dir

```
cmd=['hdfs', 'dfs', '-ls', OutDir]
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for i in process.communicate():
 if i:
    for j in i.decode('utf-8').strip().split():
       if j.endswith('snappy.parquet'):
          print('reading file ',j)
          mydf  = spark.read.format("parquet").option("inferSchema","true")\
          .option("header", "true")\
          .load(j)
          print('df built on bad file ')
          mydf.createOrReplaceTempView("dtl_rev")
          ssql="""select old-name AS new_name,
          old_col AS new_col from dtl_rev"""
          newdf=spark.sql(ssql)
          print('df built on renamed file ')
          aggdf.write.format("parquet").mode("append").save(newdir)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can not rename column name in the existing files, parquet stores schema in the data file,
we can check schema using below command
parquet-tools schema part-m-00000.parquet

we have to take backup into a temp table and re-ingest the history data.

Answer (score -1):

Try using, ALTER TABLE

```
desc p;

+-------------------------+------------+----------+--+
|        col_name         | data_type  | comment  |
+-------------------------+------------+----------+--+
| category_id             | int        |          |
| category_department_id  | int        |          |
| category_name           | string     |          |
+-------------------------+------------+----------+--+

alter table p change column category_id id int

desc p;
+-------------------------+------------+----------+--+
|        col_name         | data_type  | comment  |
+-------------------------+------------+----------+--+
| id                      | int        |          |
| category_department_id  | int        |          |
| category_name           | string     |          |
+-------------------------+------------+----------+--+
```

Comment: Alter not applycable to parquet

Comment: You cannot rename columns in parquet files.